# special minHeap, how to print all the n elements in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, merge, mergesort, heapsort, binary-heap

Speical minHeap is a minHeap which each level is sorted from left to right.
How can I print all the `n` elements by order in `O(n)` at worst case?

The minHeap is implemented by binary heap, in which the tree is a complete binary tree (see figure).

here is the example of a special minHeap:

[image]

So the result should be: `[1,3,4,5,8,10,17,18,20,22,25,30]`

Question from homework.

Comment: You may want to clarify what type of data structure you are using to store the heap.

Comment: Clearly not **MergeSort**, because **MergeSort** takes `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Is this an exercise/homework?

Comment: You can do this by comparing the node's 2 children with the node's brother, and take the smaller as your next element. I will post an answer soon

Comment: @alaa-m Consider starting from the root. since 3 is the least element, you should take it as the next element. Then, at the next step, since 4 is smallest among 4, 5 and 17, you'll take 4. Then, you'll have to decide between 20 and 25, while you should have been picking 5. Considering this, I don't believe the answer is that straightforward.

Comment: @Jim Mischel this is possible for sure

Comment: I'm pretty sure that worst case you'll need to maintain `O(n)` 'pointers' in this structure. Deciding which one to move forward will thus require `O(log n)` comparisons. Since you need to progress `O(n)` times, I would be surprised if you can get the running time below `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @user3781974: What makes you certain it's possible? If you have a solution, please don't keep us waiting.

Comment: You say "How can I print n elements". Do you mean *all* the elements, or is n a separate parameter?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Not exactly... Because say you have `40` instead of `4`, so after merging the 1st and 2nd levels in linear time, you can't skip to merge levels 3 and 5 - you will have to merge the newly created level with level 3. This means you visited level 1 and 2 twice each. Not O(n) anymore

Comment: @AlaaM: You had the right answer, with an O(n) (actually 2n) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is a parameter independent of the size of the heap, then under a standard comparison-based model, this is impossible. You will need additional restrictions, like more preexisting order than you've mentioned, or all elements of the heap being integers under a sufficiently low bound.

Suppose you have a heap of height `k`, where the root and its chain of left children have values 1, 2, 3, ... k. We can assign values >k to the k-1 right children of these nodes in any order without violating the "special minheap" condition, then assign values greater than those to fill out the rest of the heap. Printing the top 2k-1 values in this heap requires sorting k-1 values that could be in any order, which cannot be done through comparisons in less than `O(k*log(k))` time.

---

If `n` is supposed to be the size of the heap, this is straightforward. The heap invariant is unnecessary; it only matters that the layers are sorted. A mergesort merging the first and second layers, then merging each successive layer into the already-merged results, will take O(n) time. The kth merge merges 2^k-1 already-merged elements with <=2^k elements from the next layer, taking O(2^k) time. There are O(log(n)) merges, and summing O(2^k) from k=1 to k=log(n) gives O(n).

Comment: This was the argument I had in mind, but sometimes the definition of `minHeap` requires it to be a complete binary tree (as in the example). So I'm still not sure.

Comment: @WhatsUp: This argument uses a complete binary tree, so I'm not sure what problem you're seeing.

Comment: The complete heap will have about `2^k` nodes, so the problem requires printing out all of them in `O(2^k)` time. This is still slightly different from printing out the first `2k - 1` values in `O(k)` time.

Comment: @WhatsUp: The problem description sounds to me like `n` is a parameter independent of the size of the heap.

Comment: Aha, I was understanding it as the total number of nodes, as in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Each level of the heap is in ascending order. There are log(n) levels.

We can do a merge of the levels, which is O(n log k). k in this case is the number of levels, or log(n), so we know it's possible to do this in O(n * log(log n)).

The levels have 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. nodes in them. The first merge operation removes the first level, so the number of items in our merge heap becomes k-1. In the worst case, after half of the nodes have been removed, the merge heap is k-2, etc.

I don't have the math at hand, but I suspect the solution involves showing that expanding the series (i.e. keeping track of the merge heap size and multiplying by the number of nodes that go through each size heap) reduces to 2, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Correct answer, I think. By merging from top to bottom, one actually achieves `O(n)` complexity, because the sizes of the levels form a geometric series of ratio `2`.

Comment: It's O(n). The math is relatively straightforward; I've done it in my answer.